# 1.Is there a way to enable one of the parameter dropdown field in SSRS only after providing input for another dropdown parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two dropdown parameters in my report. I need the user to be able to select a value in second dropdown only after choosing a value in first parameter dropdown. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  If you use the first variable to obtain the list of values for the 2nd parameter, then it is disabled until you select a value for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Cascading Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-cascading-parameters-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15). Parameter1 might be a list of categories, run from a dataset with a query like:

```
SELECT Category FROM Categories
```

Now you want the selected category to narrow the selections for Parameter2, so the query for Parameter2 uses Parameter1 in its dataset query:

```
SELECT Item FROM Items
WHERE Category = @Parameter1
```

When you select Parameter1, the query for Parameter2 will run, returning and displaying only those items for that category.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This answer helped. Thank you.